# Develop a Snap package for project using SDL2

Tags: packaging, qt, sdl, snap

I am currently developing an application that uses joystick input and generates different wave sounds using SDL. While the implementation works without any issues, once I package my application using *snapcraft*, my application is not able to generate sounds nor getting joystick input.

The interfaces that my application uses are:

- x11
- network
- pulseaudio
- network-bind
- system-observe
- network-observe

Additionally, when running my application from a terminal, I get the following errors/warnings:

```
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
```

These warnings do not appear if I run my application the "classic" way (sudo make install). Is it possible to configure my `snapcraft.yaml` to let SDL2 work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You're running into part of the security structure, which even in `configure: devmode` still prevents the snap from doing arbitrary operations on the system. I've been fooling around [on the snappy-playpen github](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen), (which has a [gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/ubuntu/snappy-playpen)), but I am by no means an expert. If you are defining `plugs` for each of your `apps`/`parts` and are hooking them up to the ubuntu-core `slots` after `snap`ing, then you've got some serious stuff to work through. If you haven't done that, keep working at it. Have you got your `snapcraft.yaml` up anywhere?

The `snapd` component of `snappy` is still under heavy development, and `snapcraft` itself as well. What is still manual today might be better automated soon. However, I would first suggest moving your project into the `snappy-playpen` repo and getting some help from the community team and `snappy` devs. There will be an online clinic upcoming this Tuesday, 21 June. Maybe look on G+ for more details if you're interested, it'll be streamed on [Ubuntu On Air](http://ubuntuonair.com/) while it's happening.

Comment: I have also moved my project to snappy-playpen (now waiting for a merge). Thanks!